# SSO IdentityServer3 Authentication and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I have an MVC 4.5 project which will have multiple domains, for example:

1. HTTPS:// domain1 .com (secured with SSL)
2. HTTP:// domain2 .com
3. HTTP:// domain3 .com

Only the secure domain (https://domain1.com) will be used to authorize users. After signing in, Users should be authenticated across all the other domains.

**What I did to achieve this:**
I have installed identity server and made it work perfectly. But I still wonder if it is possible to achieve the following scenario:

1. The user logs in in (domain1.com) with ASP Identity.
2. A cookie is created for the user and he is authenticated now in the authorizations server (domain1.com).
3. Now, when this user comes from domain2.com (the client app), he gets redirected to identityServer3's authorize endpoint, instead of being automatically authenticated.

Is there a way I can authorize the user directly if he had already logged in with ASP Identity?

Really appreciate your help.

Iyad

Comment: Is domain2 and 3 built on top of katana? If you setup your pages under domain2 and domain3 to be protected (as required authorized), user should get bounced to domain1 and bounced back automatically

Comment: domain 1, 2 and 3 work on the same MVC application and share the same authentication system. Think about it this way: mydomain.com, mydomain.net, and mydomain.biz, they all point to the same application but only one of them is secured and allow to authenticate. So I want it to be the single signin domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup your domain 2 and 3 as implicit JavaScript client , see this [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptImplicitClient), but it doesn't sign users in automatically when they navigate to the sites after they've signed in on domain 1, you have to implement something your own to achieve that, hope [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2353) might help you

Comment: Thank you so much. I've created a test environment to test the scenario and will see if I will go with this approach or with ws_Federation which could work too.